# Elementary properties of $\sigma$ algebra

Tags: measure-theory

In my notes it says that if $\sum$ is a $\sigma$ algebra of subsets of X then it has the following property:
 $$E \ \cup F \in \sum $$
for all $E,F \in \sum$

A part of the proof says: If $E,F \in \sum$ then set $E_1=E$ and $E_n=F$ for $n\ \geq2$.

What does this part of the proof mean?

Comment: do you know what a $\sigma-$ alegbra is?

Comment: The problem here is that $E\cup F$ is a finite union of sets while your definition (I presume!) of a $\sigma$-algebra only speaks of infinite unions. The step is a way to translate from the latter to the former. (Note that this is based entirely on assumptions.)

Comment: @nephry I dont understand why $E_n=F$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $\sigma$-algebra $\sum$ has the following three properties: $$\emptyset \in \sum$$ $$E \in \sum \Rightarrow E^c \in \sum$$ and $$\{E_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \in \sum \Rightarrow \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k \in \sum.$$

Take $E_1 = E$, $E_2 = F$ and $\forall k \geq 2(E_k = \emptyset)$ or $E_k = E,$ because $\bigcup_{k \geq 2}^{\infty} E_k = E$ .

Comment: why does $E_2=F$?

Comment: It is just for convenience, since I defined the countable collection as $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$